# creating a map from two vectors

Tags: c++, stl, vector, dictionary

If I have two stl vectors vect1, vect2 and I want to produce from them a map, so first element from vect1 will correspond to first element in vect2 and so on.
How can I do that in the most simple way?

Comment: What do you want to happen when they have different sizes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> a, b;
// fill vectors here...
std::map<int, int> m;
assert(a.size() == b.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    m[a[i]] = b[i];
```

Comment: This works, but I'd replace the `assert` with an exception or something.  Nobody likes a library call that halts their program!

Comment: What happens when `a` contains duplicates ? You may want to do `if (m.find(a[i]) != m.end()) m.insert(a[i]) else throw ...`.

Comment: @Alexandre C. `insert` will return a pair with an iterator into the element and a boolean indicating whether it was inserted or it previously existed. There is no need to do the previous lookup.

Comment: @David: I should read the docs sometimes! Thanks for this. So my comment should be read `if (!m.insert(std::make_pair(a[i], b[i])).second) throw ...`

Comment: @Andre: assert is usually ignored in release builds

Comment: @Inverse: that's an additional reason not to use it, as far as I'm concerned.  Someone related using assert to "wearing a safety vest while canoeing close to the shore and removing it before going out to the middle of the lake".

Comment: If there's a duplicate key this version will overwrite it, so it will have a value of the last one encountered.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a solution that uses standard library functions (and C++0x lambdas).

```
const int data1[] = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 };
const int data2[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
std::vector<int> vec1(data1, data1 + 5);
std::vector<int> vec2(data2, data2 + 5);
std::map<int,int> map;

// create map
std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), std::inserter(map, map.end()), [](int a, int b)
{
    return std::make_pair(a, b);
});

// display map
std::for_each(map.begin(), map.end(), [](const std::pair<int,int>& p)
{
    std::cout << p.first << "," << p.second << "\n";
});
```

Note: This assumes vec1.size() is not greater than vec2.size().

Comment: you don't need the lambdas, the following works just as well in C++03 `std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), std::inserter(my_map, my_map.end()), std::make_pair<int, std::string>);`

Comment: @Nim: Maybe it's just me but MSVC++ won't accept `std::make_pair` as a binary function object.

Comment: did you try std::make_pair<int, int> ? make_pair without its template arguments would not be resolved.

Comment: @CashCow: Yes but it still  wouldn't compile. I also tried wrapping it with `std::bind` with the same result. Lambdas win again.

Answer (score 8):

We will use the version of [std::transform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) that takes 2 input sequences. (Not as well known it appears as the one that takes a single sequence).

You can pass in `std::make_pair<v1::value_type, v2::value_type>` as your transformer (op) thus in your case

```
std::vector<int> vec1, vec2;
std::map< int, int > mergedMap;
std::transform( vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), 
       std::inserter(mergedMap, mergedMap.end() ), std::make_pair<int const&,int const&> );
```

I have tested the code and it compiles fine with GNU 4.3.2

(I have also tested now with C++11. It works when I changed make_pair to take int const& rather than int).

If the two input sequences are of different length, it will be fine if the first is shorter, and later elements in the second sequence will be ignored. If the first is longer, it will produce undefined behaviour.

Comment: The standard library already has a `std::transform` algorithm that takes two sequences and a binary function object.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, erm, not the last time I looked. `std::transform` takes a sequence, and an output iterator (where the transformed result will be written)...

Comment: @Nim: It's documented on the MSDN site and http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/transform.html. There are two forms of the `std::transform` algorithm.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, shikes I missed that!! Thx for pointing that out!!

Comment: @Nim: I posted an answer with `std::transform`. I also cheated and used a C++0x lambda expression because it makes the whole thing so simple.

Comment: hehe, it must be only me then that thinks that the lambda version looks horrible... ;)

Comment: @Nim: I like being able to define the code for a one-off functor in the place where it's being used. A lambda can also be stashed in an `auto` variable if I need to pass it around or call it in multiple places. They really are neat once you get used to them.

Comment: @Nim @Blastfurnace I looked up the documentation and indeed see std::transform with 2 inputs which means just remove mine and put that in its place. Does it work with make_pair?

Comment: Ok, tested my code and it works fine. So possible in one statement all along using the standard library.

Comment: This won't compile with the -std=c++11 option. I get the same error with g++, clang++ and icpc: `/usr/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_algo.h:4988:46: error: cannot bind ‘int’ lvalue to ‘int&&’`
The lambda works fine and is probably the way to go when it comes to c++11.

Comment: By the way, if you made this into a template you'd need a typename before v1::value_type and v2::value_type.

Comment: If there is a duplicate key here the first one counts and the value will be whichever happened first.

For C++11 transform takes a lambda so use it. I am surprised though that this wouldn't compile. Which bit is faulty?

Comment: That C++11 broke working code is something I need to ask on here... I will check it wasn't broken before.

Comment: Incidentally if the sequences are different lengths here, it will use the length of the first sequence and will be UB if the first is longer than the second.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight variation that uses boost's `zip_iterator`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

// this is our map type
typedef std::map<int, std::string> map_t;

// this functor will be called for each "pair"
struct map_adder :
  public std::unary_function<const boost::tuple<const int&, const std::string&>&, void>
{
  map_adder(map_t& my_map) : _my_map(my_map){}

  void operator()(const boost::tuple<const int&, const std::string&>& t) const
  {
    _my_map.insert(std::make_pair(t.get<0>(), t.get<1>()));
  }

private:
  mutable map_t& _my_map;
};

int main(void)
{
  // test setup
  std::vector<int> keys;
  std::vector<std::string> values;
  keys.push_back(1);
  keys.push_back(2);
  keys.push_back(3);
  keys.push_back(4);

  values.push_back("1");
  values.push_back("2");
  values.push_back("3");
  values.push_back("4");

  std::vector<int>::const_iterator beg1 = keys.begin();
  std::vector<int>::const_iterator end1 = keys.end();
  std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator beg2 = values.begin();
  std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator end2 = values.end();

  // destination
  map_t my_map;

  // functor to actually add
  map_adder adder(my_map);

  // simply iterate over...
  std::for_each(
    boost::make_zip_iterator(
      boost::make_tuple(beg1, beg2)
      ),
    boost::make_zip_iterator(
      boost::make_tuple(end1, end2)
      ),
    adder
  );

  std::cout << "size of map: " << my_map.size() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

okay, here is a *simpler* version using `std::transform`, I'm not aware of something which already exists which can convert a `boost::tuple` to a `std::pair` hence my simple function...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

// this is our map type
typedef std::map<int, std::string> map_t;

map_t::value_type adapt_tuple(const boost::tuple<const map_t::key_type&, const map_t::mapped_type&>& t)
{
  return map_t::value_type(t.get<0>(), t.get<1>());
}

int main(void)
{
  std::vector<int> keys;
  std::vector<std::string> values;
  keys.push_back(1);
  keys.push_back(2);
  keys.push_back(3);
  keys.push_back(4);

  values.push_back("1");
  values.push_back("2");
  values.push_back("3");
  values.push_back("4");

  std::vector<int>::const_iterator beg1 = keys.begin();
  std::vector<int>::const_iterator end1 = keys.end();
  std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator beg2 = values.begin();
  std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator end2 = values.end();

  map_t my_map;

  // simply iterate over...
  std::transform(
    boost::make_zip_iterator(
      boost::make_tuple(beg1, beg2)
      ),
    boost::make_zip_iterator(
      boost::make_tuple(end1, end2)
      ),
    std::inserter(my_map, my_map.end()),
    adapt_tuple
    );

  std::cout << "size of map: " << my_map.size() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can we replace for_each with transform, which would give you a solution similar to mine?

Comment: @CashCow, here you go, the `std::transform` version, the only thing I'm not aware of is something that can already adapt a `boost::tuple` to a `std::pair`, but where's the fun in conforming?? ;)

Answer (score 0):

assuming, you are going to ignore the extra (size of vect1 != size of vect2), this could be a solution:

```
map<T1, T2> target; //vector<T1> vect1, vector<T2> vect2;
vector<T1>::iterator it1 = vect1.begin();
vector<T2>::iterator it2 = vect2.begin();
while(it1 != vect1.end() && it2 != vect2.end())
{
target.insert(std::make_pair(*it1, *it2));
it1++;it2++;
}
```

EDIT : Thanks Nim for pointing out *it1 thing.