# What is the computationally efficient way to merge two associated std::stack into a std::map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, merge, stack

I have a function that generates two `std::stack`s of associated values with one to one correspondence between the elements. To make it easier for me to transfer the values between the functions I wish to merge the two stacks into a map.

As of now I pop out each element in both the stack, form a `std::pair` and insert it into my `std::map` like this:

```
/* peaks_x and peaks_y are the stacks that I 
want to merge into the map called peaksmap which is 
given as argument to this function */
/* create the stacks*/
std::stack<int> peaks_x;
std::stack<float> peaks_y; 
/* the following function populates the values needed */
populatepeakvalues(&peaks_x,&peaks_y);
/* merging here into a map*/
while(!peaks_x.empty() && !peaks_y.empty() ) {
   peaksmap->insert(std::pair<int,float>(peaks_x.top(),peaks_y.top()));
   peaks_x.pop(); 
   peaks_y.pop();
}
```

Is this the best way or Is there any computationally faster way to do it? May be using pointers?

Note: I cannot edit the function `populatepeakvalues` to output a map because I don't have permissions.

Comment: Why not generate a map at the first place?

Comment: @EricZ I am not allowed to touch the function as it is used my so many other parts of the project. I actually only have read permissions for the file.

Comment: @VivekVK You're lacking a [lot of context](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I guess I have given you all the information needed. In short I just to merge a stack<key> with a stack<value> to form a map<key,value> in the most computationally efficient way.

Comment: @VivekVK _"I guess I have given you all the information needed ..."_ been guessing wrong. Please provide a [minimal sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), proving your hypothesis ***"Is this the best way ..."***. We can't know without seeing the actual code. Also note asking for _'Is this the best way'_ is rarely considered an on topic question here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have given the code that I have used now. Please look into it. Also when I say "the best way" , I mean it has the minimum computational complexity. I  edited that as well.

Comment: @VivekVK _'I have given the code that I have used now. ...'_ C'mon that's quite far off, being a valid [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Vivek, please check out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946424/creating-a-map-from-two-vectors

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ please tell me what other information you need.

Comment: Why don't you make a `std::pair` of the two stacks? That's a simple unitary object you can ship around as you please, and it's a lot cheaper to put together (and take apart).

Comment: @rici thats a wonderful workaround. Why didn't I think of that? Thanks. But still I want to know if what I asked is possible. else will use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be hard to beat this without getting into the weeds.  For a plain old `std::stack`, the backing store is a `std::deque`. The `pop()` operation just moves a pointer that points to the end of the deque.  This means that you are just using pointers in the background.

However, you are iterating over the `std::deque` backwards, which is usually the worst way to access memory.  For a small `std::stack`, it does not matter.  For a large `std::stack`, memory bandwith will make the loop slow.  You might be able to get around that with creative hacks to directly access the embedded `std::deque`.  That *will* void your warranty.