# How to transform a vector of struct into a map using STL

Tags: c++, vector, stl, c++03

I have a `std::vector<Person> v` with

```
struct Person
{
    Person(int i,std::string n) {Age=i; this->name=n;};
    int GetAge() { return this->Age; };
    std::string GetName() { return this->name; };
    private:
    int Age;
    std::string name;
};
```

and I need to transform to `std::map<std::string,int> persons`

I got stuck when coding something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bd19155216ef613) :

```
std::transform(v.begin(),v.end(),
  std::inserter(persons,persons.end()), 
  std::make_pair<std::string,int>(boost::bind(&Person::GetName,_1)),  (boost::bind(&Person::GetAge,_1)));
```

**What is the best way to transform the `vector<Person> v` into `map<std::string,int> persons` by using stl algorithm in c++03?**

Comment: Copy the information from each vector element with `for_each`?

Comment: yes, boost is allowed.

Comment: @adam10603: So it is: 1. Create the vector of keys. 2. Create the vector of values. 3. Combine both to map like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946424/creating-a-map-from-two-vectors (Answer from CashCow). Nice idea, Thanks

Comment: @ToBe That's not really what I meant. Loop through your vector of persons with for_each, and in the third argument, specify a function that does this: `personMap[personVec.name] = personVec.age;`. Or actually, a simple for loop with this inside its body would do just fine as well.

Comment: @adam10603. Right, got your point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMO, a simple for loop is a lot clearer here..

```
for (vector<Person>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
  persons.insert(make_pair(i->GetName(), i->GetAge()));
```

You can't possibly argue that the `bind` mess you'll need is clearer than the above..

And in C++11, this becomes

```
for (auto const& p : v)
  persons.emplace(p.GetName(), p.GetAge());
```

Even more concise...

Basically, it's nice to use algorithms, but don't use them just for the sake of using them..

Comment: for(auto const & i : v) better? - ah you beat me to it :p

Comment: In C++11 it looks really nice, I wish I could use this :-( . Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

You just need to bind `std::make_pair` as well:

```
  std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(),
    std::inserter(persons, persons.end()),
    boost::bind(std::make_pair<std::string, int>,
      boost::bind(&Person::GetName, _1),
      boost::bind(&Person::GetAge, _1)));
```

Comment: Although, this was actually the thing I was trying to implement, I am going to accept answer of nim. It was good to see both options and I will go with the simple for loop. Thanks for your answer