# Lookup multiple strings in a vector in a map's keys

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a list of key and values. There is another vector that has some of the keys. I want to search these keys in the list and use the corresponding values for further calculations.

```
#Inside R environment
simil<-list("key"=c("A","B","C","D"),"val"=c(1.2,3.2,2.0,1.9)) 
someVec = c("B","D")

//CPP code
#include <RcppEigen>
#include <map>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector someFunc(GenericVector simil, CharacterVector someVec){
  List sim(simil);
  std::map<std::string, double> mymap;
  std::map<std::string, double>::iterator it;
  CharacterVector keys = sim["key"];
  NumericVector vals = sim["val"];

  map[keys] = vals;

  for(int i=0;i<someVec.size();i++){
       it = mymap.find(someVec(i));

      if(it!=mymap.end()){
        // some logic here
  }

}
```

I was not sure if `map[keys] = vals` would work as this looks more like an R statement but the compiler does not throw any error in this line. The issue is with using the .find() on the map.
It throws an error : No matching member function for call to find.

How can I search for the keys in that map? Even the `mymap.count(someVec(i))>0` shows an error.

Comment: You use your `someVec` as a function at `it = mymap.find(someVec(i));` Try using parenthesis `[i]` or the safer `.at(i)` function to access vector elements;

Comment: @AlexanderS That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: `someVec` is a `CharacterVector` whereas the `mymap.find` expects a `std::string`

Comment: creating a map from two vectors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946424/creating-a-map-from-two-vectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was not sure if map[keys] = vals would work as this looks more like an R statement but the compiler does not throw any error in this line.

I'm not sure why that compiles but it definitely won't do what you expect it to do; `std::map` is a C++ class and doesn't observe R's vectorized semantics. It has a [few different constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) which may be used to populate it with data, but in your case, the simplest approach may be to just loop over your input and fill it iteratively.

> The issue is with using the .find() on the map. It throws an error : No matching member function for call to find.

I suspect this has to do with the fact that `CharacterVector::operator[]` returns a `string_proxy` (or `const_string_proxy`, depending on the context). This will not implicitly convert to `std::string`, but you can use `Rcpp::as<std::string>` to perform an explicit conversion.

All together,

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <map>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector find_keys(List keyvals, CharacterVector morekeys) {
    std::map<std::string, double> mymap;
    std::map<std::string, double>::iterator it;

    CharacterVector keys = keyvals["key"];
    NumericVector vals = keyvals["val"];

    R_xlen_t i = 0, n = keys.size(), m = morekeys.size();
    NumericVector res(m, NA_REAL);

    // fill map
    for (; i < n; i++) {
        mymap[as<std::string>(keys[i])] = vals[i];
    }

    // look up potential keys
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        it = mymap.find(as<std::string>(morekeys[i]));
        if (it != mymap.end()) {
            res[i] = it->second;
        }
    }

    return res;
}

/*** R

keyvals <-list(
    key = c("A","B","C","D"),
    val = c(1.2,3.2,2.0,1.9)
)
morekeys = c("B", "D", "x")

find_keys(keyvals, morekeys)
# [1] 3.2 1.9  NA

*/
```

---

Alternatively, the Rcpp `wrap` / `as` specializations know how to handle conversions between `CharacterVector` and `std::vector<std::string>` "out of the box", i.e.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector find_keys2(List keyvals, const std::vector<std::string>& morekeys) {
    // ...

    std::vector<std::string> keys = as<std::vector<std::string> >(keyvals["key"]);
    // ...

    // fill map
    for (; i < n; i++) {
        mymap[keys[i]] = vals[i];
    }

    // look up potential keys
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        it = mymap.find(morekeys[i]);
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: In the second proposition, does the & in the prototype make a difference ? The conversion to a vector of strings requires copying anyway, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Elvis you are correct; it's just a habit of writing it that way.

Comment: Thanks  for the precision!